# Searching Android API documentation from inside Android Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio

Inside MSVC pressing F1 while the carrot is located under an API class or function name launches a browser window that opens onto the appropriate MSDN documentation. Is there anything available to bring up the Android docs in a similarly convenient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no similar feature available in Android Studio but has similar alternatives.

Afaik, what available like this *(I use Eclipse keymap*) **:**

• <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Left Click` to find the source of current code which is hovered upon. This is useful because they have a good comment-documentation for methods. So I usually don't need to go-to references.

• <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to find usages of current method hovered upon.

• <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> for finding sample code regarding method/Object hovered upon.

---

You can find a full list of available shortcuts here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts

---

Another useful thing available is: **Quick Documentation** (This is maybe what you're looking for)

***Enabling***:

[image]

***Usage***:

[image]